# Why is that I'm able to successfully return a large np.float128 but when I try to create the same np.float128 in numpy I just get inf?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, floating-point, precision, exp

I'm writing a function to take the exponent of a large number:

```
def exp_large_float(x):
    return np.exp(np.float128(np.array([x])))

result = exp_large_float(800.)
print(result)
>>> [2.72637457e+347]

print(result.dtype)
>>> float128
```

I'm testing that `result` is what I intend so I want to create a "ground truth" array and compare it to the output of `exp_large_float`:

```
ground_truth = np.float128(2.72637457e+347)
print(ground_truth)
>>> inf
```

Why is that I'm able to successfully return a `np.float128` of `2.72637457e+347` but when I try to create this same thing in `numpy` I just get `inf`?

I'm using python version 2.7.15.

Comment: *Python* converts `2.72637457e+347` to `inf` before it gets passed to numpy.  Python doesn't have 128 bit floating point values.

Comment: python can clearly handle a `np.float128(2.72637457e+347)` as I'm able to return it. How can I create this object?

Comment: `ground_truth = np.float128(["2.72637457e+347"])`

Comment: You are returning a NumPy object.  The Python interpreter doesn't handle `2.72637457e+347`.  Try `print 2.72637457e+347` in the interactive shell.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Your comment worked! If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, nice, I forgot that the NumPy objects will convert strings.  You can also write `np.float128("2.72637457e+347") `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @Warren Weckesser your code doesn't work because

```
2.72637457e+347
```

is a float literal in Python so it is interpreted as standard (presumably 64bit) float and becomes `inf` *before* it is  passed on to the `float128` factory.

You can avoid this by passing your argument as a string.

```
ground_truth = np.float128("2.72637457e+347")
```